# Hyperledger Fabric v1 : Error connecting to orderer:7050 due to grpc: timed out when dialing

Tags: hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to test the latest version of Hyperledger Fabric, the v1 in incubation.  I have an issue with the latest version of Hyperledger Fabric.

I'm following the instructions here to install Fabric:
https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/asset_setup/

I'm using Docker to spawn network entities & create/join a channel :

`sudo docker --version 
 Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3`

`sudo docker-compose --version
 docker-compose version 1.11.2, build dfed245`

When I'm performing :

```
sudo docker-compose -f docker-compose-gettingstarted.yml up
```

My five containers are running :

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                                          COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                            NAMES
f1b6d6128d43        sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0      "sh -c './channel_..."   21 minutes ago      Up About a minute                                                    cli
8f9df755c160        sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0      "peer node start -..."   21 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8056->7051/tcp                           peer2
2de6ee624d28        sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0      "peer node start -..."   21 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8055->7051/tcp                           peer1
31ac53b6e5db        sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0      "peer node start -..."   21 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8051->7051/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8053->7053/tcp   peer0
d98fc2a8652f        sfhackfest22017/fabric-ca:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-6294c57        "sh -c 'sleep 10; ..."   21 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8054->7054/tcp                           ca
07dcfceb86cc        sfhackfest22017/fabric-orderer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0   "orderer"                21 minutes ago      Up About a minute   0.0.0.0:8050->7050/tcp                           orderer
```

but I get this error on the last line :

```
 2017-03-01 14:55:32.183 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 016 Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [peer] GetManagerForChain -> INFO 017 Created new msp manager for chain testchainid
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] Setup -> INFO 018 Setting up the MSP manager (1 msps)
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] Setup -> INFO 019 Setting up MSP
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] NewBccspMsp -> INFO 01a Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] Setup -> INFO 01b Setting up MSP instance DEFAULT
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 01c Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.270 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 01d Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.271 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 01e Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.271 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 01f Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 020 Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 021 Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [msp] newIdentity -> INFO 022 Creating identity instance for ID &{DEFAULT IDENTITY}
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [msp] Setup -> INFO 023 MSP manager setup complete, setup 1 msps
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [logging] InitFromViper -> DEBU 024 Setting default logging level to DEBUG for command 'channel'
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [peer] GetLocalMSP -> INFO 025 Returning existing local MSP
cli               | 2017-03-01 14:55:32.275 UTC [msp] GetDefaultSigningIdentity -> INFO 026 Obtaining default signing identity
cli               | Error: Error getting broadcast client: Error connecting to orderer:7050 due to grpc: timed out when dialing
```

How can I fix it ?

And when I perform :

```
sudo docker exec -it cli bash
[sudo] Mot de passe de blockchain : 
root@f1b6d6128d43:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer# cat results.txt
ERROR on CHANNEL CREATION
```

Here is my Docker_compose.yml :

```
version: '2'
networks:
   bridge:

services:

  ccenv_latest:
    container_name: ccenv_latest
    build: ./ccenv
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:latest
    volumes:
        - ./ccenv:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ccenv

  ccenv_snapshot:
    container_name: ccenv_snapshot
    build: ./ccenv
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ccenv:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    volumes:
        - ./ccenv:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer/ccenv

  ca:
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-ca:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-6294c57
    ports:
      - 8054:7054
    environment:
      - CA_CERTIFICATE=peerOrg0_cert.pem
      - CA_KEY_CERTIFICATE=peerOrg0_pk.pem
    volumes:
        - ./tmp/ca:/.fabric-ca
    command: sh -c 'sleep 10; fabric-ca server start -ca /.fabric-ca/$$CA_CERTIFICATE -ca-key /.fabric-ca/$$CA_KEY_CERTIFICATE -config /etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca/server-config.json -address "0.0.0.0"'
    container_name: ca


  orderer:
    container_name: orderer
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-orderer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    environment:
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LEDGERTYPE=ram
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BATCHTIMEOUT=10s
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_BATCHSIZE_MAXMESSAGECOUNT=10
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_MAXWINDOWSIZE=1000
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_ORDERERTYPE=solo
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LOGLEVEL=debug
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENADDRESS=0.0.0.0
      - ORDERER_GENERAL_LISTENPORT=7050
      - ORDERER_RAMLEDGER_HISTORY_SIZE=100
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/orderer
    command: orderer
    ports:
      - 8050:7050
    networks:
      - bridge

  peer0:
    container_name: peer0
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=peer0
      - CORE_NEXT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer0
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_IGNORESECURITY=true

    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    ports:
      - 8051:7051
      - 8053:7053
    links:
      - orderer:orderer
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./tmp/peer0:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig
    networks:
      - bridge

  peer1:
    container_name: peer1
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=peer0
      - CORE_NEXT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer1
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_IGNORESECURITY=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    ports:
      - 8055:7051
    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    links:
      - orderer:orderer
      - peer0:peer0
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./tmp/peer1:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig
    networks:
      - bridge

  peer2:
    container_name: peer2
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    environment:
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_PEER_NETWORKID=peer0
      - CORE_NEXT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_ID=peer2
      - CORE_PEER_PROFILE_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_ORGLEADER=true
      - CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_IGNORESECURITY=true
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer

    ports:
      - 8056:7051
    command: peer node start --peer-defaultchain=false
    links:
      - orderer:orderer
      - peer0:peer0
      - peer1:peer1
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        - ./tmp/peer2:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig
    networks:
      - bridge

  cli:
    container_name: cli
    image: sfhackfest22017/fabric-peer:x86_64-0.7.0-snapshot-c7b3fe0
    tty: true
    environment:
      - GOPATH=/opt/gopath
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESSAUTODETECT=true
      - CORE_VM_ENDPOINT=unix:///host/var/run/docker.sock
      - CORE_LOGGING_LEVEL=DEBUG
      - CORE_NEXT=true
      - CORE_PEER_ID=cli
      - CORE_PEER_ENDORSER_ENABLED=true
      - CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050
      - CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer0:7051
    working_dir: /opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer
    command: sh -c './channel_test.sh; sleep 10000'
#   command: /bin/sh
    links:
      - orderer:orderer
      - peer0:peer0
      - peer1:peer1
      - peer2:peer2
    volumes:
        - /var/run/:/host/var/run/
        #in the "- <HOST>:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/" mapping below, the HOST part
        #should be modified to the path on the host. This will work as is in the Vagrant environment
        - ./src/github.com/example_cc/example_cc.go:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/examples/example_cc.go
        - ./tmp/peer3:/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig
        - ./channel_test.sh:/opt/gopath/src/github.com/hyperledger/fabric/peer/channel_test.sh
    networks:
      - bridge
```

And this is my channel_test.sh :

```
#!/bin/sh

# find address of peer0 in your network
PEER0_IP_ADDRESS=`perl -e 'use Socket; $a = inet_ntoa(inet_aton("peer0")); print "$a\n";'`

# create an anchor file
cat<<EOF>anchorPeer.txt
$PEER0_IP_ADDRESS
7051
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
EOF

#create
echo "Creating channel on Orderer"
CORE_PEER_GOSSIP_IGNORESECURITY=true CORE_PEER_MSPCONFIGPATH=/etc/hyperledger/fabric/msp/sampleconfig CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050 peer channel create -c myc1 -a anchorPeer.txt >>log.txt 2>&1
cat log.txt
   grep -q "Exiting" log.txt
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "ERROR on CHANNEL CREATION" >> results.txt
      exit 1
   fi
echo "SUCCESSFUL CHANNEL CREATION" >> results.txt
sleep 5
TOTAL_PEERS=3
i=0
while test $i -lt $TOTAL_PEERS  
do
echo "###################################### Joining peer$i"
CORE_PEER_COMMITTER_LEDGER_ORDERER=orderer:7050 CORE_PEER_ADDRESS=peer$i:7051 peer channel join -b myc1.block >>log.txt 2>&1
cat log.txt
echo '-------------------------------------------------'
grep -q "Join Result: " log.txt
   if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
      echo "ERROR on JOIN CHANNEL" >> results.txt
      exit 1
   fi
echo "SUCCESSFUL JOIN CHANNEL on PEER$i" >> results.txt
echo "SUCCESSFUL JOIN CHANNEL on PEER$i"
i=$((i+1))
sleep 10
done
echo "Peer0 , Peer1 and Peer2 are added to the channel myc1"
cat log.txt
exit 0
```

Comment: I'm stuck at the very same problem. Could you solve it? Would appreciate your insights.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this ?

Answer (score 3):

i faced similar problem and found it’s DNS issue then corrected at "hosts" file. the cause is the hostname “orderer". FYR.

Answer (score 0):

What OS you are using? I had the same issue running this getting started guide with VirtualBox running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Windows 7. After that I tried installing Ubuntu side-by-side with Windows and it worked from the first shot.

Answer (score 0):

May be because of docker containers are in the different container .

If the new organization in the different network the peers can not communicate with Orderer which is in the  other network.

check the networks : docker network ls